# Automatically redirecting users to a deep link in chrome is not working

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, deep-linking, http-redirect

I am trying to do deep linking such that when a user opens a webpage it automatically opens the app

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>
    <a href="myapp://data/">Open App</a>
    <script>
     window.location = 'myapp://data/';
  
     link = document.querySelector('a')
     link.click();
    </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Currently when the user clicks the link, everything works but nothing works if i try to automatically trigger the deep link, neither using window.location for redirect or triggering a click event on the link seems to be working.

I need a way to automatically redirect to the deep link and not wait for the user to click on the "Open App" link

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Deep linking will not work if the event is not user-driven. By default, Chrome is the browser that handles deep linking in Android.

> And Chrome doesn't launch an external app for a given Intent URI in
> the following cases.
>
> - When the Intent URI is redirected from a typed in URL.
> - When the Intent URI is initiated without user gesture.

See: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/android/intents/